# Does Java's Condition::await() support to have a predicate/function?

Tags: java, function, async-await, conditional-statements, predicate

From java doc 1.8, seems Condition only has `await()`, `await(long, TimeUnit)`, `awaitNanos()`, etc.

It doesn't have a function that looks like Condition.await(()->xxxxx) to wait until a condition is met. c++11 condition_variable supports to have `cv.wait(mutex, predicate_function)` so we can use a lambda function as a parameter to control when condition_variable should return from wait/await.

Does java support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), the C++ `condition_variable::wait` overload is just checking the predicate when a notification comes through and is equivalent to

> ```
> while (!stop_waiting()) {
>     wait(lock);
> }
> ```

So we can simply do the same thing in Java.

```
while (!someCondition()) {
    conditionVariable.await();
}
```